# Empty error object produced by ffprobe in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, ffprobe, fluent-ffmpeg

**Update**: After more digging I found [an open GitHub issue](https://github.com/SavageCore/node-ffprobe-installer/issues/121) where others appear to be encountering the same behavior.

---

I have a Google Cloud Function (2nd gen) in which I am trying to use `ffprobe` to get metadata from a video file stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. It is my understanding that I can generate a signed url and, by passing that directly to ffprobe, avoid loading the entire video file into memory. I generate a signed url and pass it to `ffprobe`, and then parse the output like so:

```
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'
import ffprobeStatic from 'ffprobe-static'

async function getVideoData(srcFile: File) {
    const [signedUrl] = await srcFile.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: (new Date()).getMilliseconds() + 60_000,
    })

    const videoData: ffmpeg.FfprobeData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobeStatic.path)
        ffmpeg.ffprobe(signedUrl, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })

    return videoData
}
```

This code works (with the same signed URL) locally on my macOS machine, but does not when deployed in a 2nd generation Google Cloud Function. In the latter case, `data` is `undefined` and `err` is `{}`.

My main question is how to properly use `ffprobe` in 2nd gen Google Cloud Functions. I have tried to research this but documentation on ffmpeg/ffprobe on GCP is sparse. I'm also trying to figure out exactly why the error object `err` is empty...it's not very helpful

Additional info:

- Environment: Google Cloud Functions 2nd Gen
- Runtime: Node 20
- "ffprobe-static": "3.1.0",
- "fluent-ffmpeg": "2.1.2"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to narrow down the use case, can you try to ffprobe a local video file? And does ffprobeStatic.path point to an executable, maybe it's inaccessible in your environment?

Comment: @mortalis good call. When I download the file to the Cloud Functions instance first and then provide its local URL to ffprobe it seems to work. For some reason it does not work on Cloud Functions with the signed URL, but using the same exact signed URL works on my local machine. Very odd to me.

Comment: ok, so ffprobe is in place and working correct, the problem is the source, one theory is some kind of access restriction for external URLs (maybe firewall, or cross-origin stuff). Maybe try also with a URL pointing to a direct media file on the web (on some file storage or github raw file)

Comment: @mortalis I just now tried with a URL for a direct media file on the web and ran into the same problem. So as far as I can tell, ffprobe/fluent-ffmpeg is having some issue with remote URLs...but only in the cloud function environment. Then I tried using Node's fetch API to first download the file from the signed URL and then pass the local URL in, and that worked...which makes me doubt the firewall idea. It only doesn't work in the CF environment when giving the remote URL directly to ffprobe, and the lack of an error message makes it challenging to find out why.

Comment: I now tried running ffprobe directly without fluent-ffmpeg, in a spawned child process, and have learned a little bit more. It worked when given a local url, but again when I provide the remote URL in the Cloud Function environment there was an error. However, this time I was able to see `Uncaught signal: 11, pid=16, tid=16, fault_addr=99.`. Now I'm trying to figure out what is causing signal 11.

Comment: Same issue here